# Is there a way to make one <td> display on its own row?

Tags: html, css

I need to make one row contain 4 cells as follows: the first three cells on one line and the last cell takes its own line under the first three spanning across all of them. Like so:

```
----------------------------------  <---Start Row
|          |          |          |
|  Cell 1  |  Cell 2  |  Cell 3  | 
|          |          |          |
----------------------------------
|                                |
|              Cell 4            |
|                                |
----------------------------------  <---End Row
```

Is there a way in HTML to do this?

Comment: As I say in my answer, I do not believe this is possible with 4 cells in a single row.  If that is the only HTML that you're able to generate, are you open to a jQuery answer that will solve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for the [`colspan`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#attributes-common-to-td-and-th-elements) attribute...

```
<tr>
  <td>Cell 1</td>
  <td>Cell 2</td>
  <td>Cell 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3">Cell 4</td>
</tr>
```

The colspan will allow you to "span" a single cell over multiple **columns**. The vertical partner to this attribute is `rowspan` which will allow you to span a single cell over multiple **rows**

---

However, in direct answer to your question, I do not believe it is possible have the 4th cell within a row appear on the next row.

My understanding is that you will have to create 2 separate rows to achieve what you're after.  (I will be happy to remove my answer should somebody prove me wrong)

---

Based on the above, if a jQuery answer is acceptable, you could do the following...

```js
$(function() {
  // Get the last child, detach from the row and add colspan
  $lastTd = $("table tr td:last-child").detach().attr("colspan", "3");
  // Create a new row, add the detached cell, and add to the table
  $("table").append($("<tr></tr>").append($lastTd));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td>Cell 3</td>
    <td>Cell 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think he said single row with 4 cells.

Comment: I was thinking all sorts of crazy code till I saw your answer. Completely forgot about `colspan` in the HTML5 world.

Comment: Indeed @Reddy, I've just added an extra bit when I realised that

Comment: Yes, I do need this to be in one row. I am trying to add a sorting feature to this table and and I need these two rows to stay together while sorting. Having two separate rows will sort both and Cell 4 will no longer be right after Cell 1,2,and 3.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense @MrX - then my understanding is that you're going to struggle. However, I would be interested to see what other solutions become available

Comment: If you're sorting client-side (as I assume you are)... then can the value you're sorting against be included as part of the attribute of the first cell of each row (making sure the 1st row of the pair and the 2nd row of the pair are marked in such a way to keep them together and the right order)?  (Actually, now that I've written it, that will get quite complex if you're sorting on multiple columns)

Comment: yes exactly, I am sorting on multiple columns. Though that's a pretty good idea - making these columns hidden or so.  I'll see if I can fiddle with this ( and if it'll be efficient )

Comment: this approach partially worked. Though, when flipping the table (when moving from ascending to descending order) Cell 4 will display before Cell 1,2 and 3.

Comment: Does your sorting allow for multiple "field"? If so, can you do `field1 asc, field2 asc` on the first click and then `field1 desc, field2 asc` on the second click, where the field2 would always be the paired rows?

Comment: I made a separate comparer to use when sorting in descending order. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: You're welcome @MrX, glad I could help in some way :-)  Good luck with the rest of your project

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how clean this might be But My solution is with single tr and  4 td's

```css
td {
   border: 1px solid black;
}

tr{
  width:120px;
  height:50px;
  display: table-caption;
}

tr >td{ 
  width:40px;   
}

tr > td:nth-child(4)
{
   width:120px; 
   position:absolute;
   display:block;  
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>full width td</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>full width td</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>full width td</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: wouldn't this make the second row display over the first row?

Comment: this will not work correctly if the table had headers.

Comment: @MrX if its only for design purpose then you can have a single td and then a div inside it to have a layout like you want. will that work for you?